# Best way to store golang map[string]interface into data store

Tags: json, go, deserialization

**Scenario**: I am having a arbitrary JSON size ranging from 300 KB - 6.5 MB read from MongoDB. Since it is very much arbitrary/dynamic data I cannot have struct type defined in golang, So I am using `map[sting]interface{}` type. And string of JSON data is parsed by using [`encoding/json`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json)'s [`Unmarshal`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) method. Some what similar to what is mentioned in [Generic JSON with interface{}](http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go).

**Issue**: But the problem is its taking more time (around 30ms to 180ms) to parse the string json into `map[string]interface{}`. (Comparing to php parsing json using json_encode/decode / igbinary/ msgpack)

**Question**: Is there any way to pre-process it and store in cache?

I mean parse string into `map[string]interface{}` and serialize it and store to some cache, then when we retrieve it should not take much time to unserialization and proceed with execution.

Note: I am Newbie for the golang any suggestion are highly appriciated. Thanks

**Updates**: Serialization using [`Gob`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/), [`binary`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) built-in package & [Msgpack implementation for Golang](https://github.com/vmihailenco/msgpack) package are already tried. No luck, No improvement in the time to unserialization.

Comment: Check out the [`encoding/gob`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) package.

Comment: @icza I had tried that. Forgot to mention it over here will update

Comment: You say that the parsing is taking *more time*. More time than what ? That said, I would suggest either storing your data in a serialized format, or retrieving them in a background process to have them handy when you need them (that may be complex, thought).

Comment: Storing data in a serialized format would probably need a change in the database you're using: using MongoDB without JSON sounds like a bad idea for me…

Comment: @Elwinar: Updated the question. But I was comparing with php's performance.

Comment: Do your data really need to use `map[string]interface{}` ? You could try unmarshalling to a base struct that would enable you to find the real type you need to use…

Comment: @Elwinar When I tried gob/binary or msg pack the data which got store in cache was in uint8/byte but looking into it. Its was just string converted to bytes array. No extra data I mean meta data of object representation of golang's `map[string]interface{}` And more over all of it no performance gain was observed. Anyways Thanks for your time & help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79394/discussion-between-elwinar-and-amol-m-kulkarni).

Comment: Given the parameters you laid out--the data has to come as a huge JSON blob whose structure is not known at compile time--it's plausible (de/re)serialization will just be slow. It seems like you have to change some part of the problem definition: break up the mega-document so you don't have to deal with the whole thing at once, keep the `map` in RAM instead of caching a reserialized blob, or define some spec so you can keep a `struct` instead of maps.

Comment: Of those, breaking it up seems esp. appealing: 6.5 MB seems like an unwieldy-sized blob to be tossing around as a single unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library package for JSON is notoriously slow. There is a good reason for that: it use RTTI to provide a really flexible interface that is really simple. Hence the unmarshalling being slower than PHP's…

Fortunately, there is an alternative way, which is to implement the `json.Unmarshaller` interface on the types you want to use. If this interface is implemented, the package will use it instead of its standard method so you can see huge performance boosts.

And to help you, there is a small group of tools that appeared, among which:

- https://godoc.org/github.com/benbjohnson/megajson
- https://godoc.org/github.com/pquerna/ffjson

(listing here the main players from memory, there must be others)

These tools will generate tailored implementations of the `json.Unmarshaller` interface for the types you requested. And with `go:generate`, you can even integrate them seamlessly to your build step.